# Estimated UITableView content size

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, autolayout

I'm using custom cells with autolayout and UITableViewAutomaticDimension. I need to know what will be the final content size of UITableView (if it will be bigger than some float).

tableView.contentSize is giving me number based on estimated row size times number of rows.

```
for(int i = 0; i< [self.items count]; i++){
    CGRect rect = [self.tableview rectForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0]];

    NSLog(@"%f",rect.size.height);
}
```

> 2014-12-07 18:42:18.036 App[42830:4312574] 48.500000 2014-12-07
>   18:42:18.039 App[42830:4312574] 48.500000

Comment: You can iterate through every index path and ask the table view for that row's height. Add all of the heights together. This will probably block your main thread for a few seconds, so if you can solve your problem another way, you should.

Comment: Sadly this is returning the estimated size property as well (or nib size)

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to check? Have you tried using `rectForRowAtIndexPath:`?

Comment: updated with code and output